# CASE statement within a JOIN query in SQL

Tags: sql, join, case-statement

This query is to print the JOINED tables with the `creditcard` column showing "cash" for every row
where there is no card name.

I wrote the following, but it results in error:

```
SELECT  st.Name Territoryname,pp.LastName SalesPerson,ps.Name ShipMethod,
        sc.CardType CreditCardType,
        soh.OrderDate,soh.TotalDue
FROM    Sales.SalesOrderHeader soh
JOIN    Person.Person pp
ON      soh.SalesPersonID=pp.BusinessEntityID
JOIN    Purchasing.ShipMethod ps
ON      ps.ShipMethodID=soh.ShipMethodID
JOIN    Sales.CreditCard sc (CASE WHEN sc.CardType='Distinguish' THEN 'Cash' ELSE sc.CardType     END),
ON      sc.CreditCardID=soh.CreditCardID
JOIN    Sales.SalesTerritory st
ON      st.TerritoryID=soh.TerritoryID
```

Comment: It depends on where I put the statement. In this case the error is "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'"

Comment: The syntax in the code above is NOW correct and it won't throw any errors.

Comment: Please don't edit the question to provide a solution. Instead, post an answer and explain what you've changed and why.

Comment: I ran the case as shown above, but it gave the EXACT same error code

Comment: AND please DONT edit my question. I have restored it as I asked it originally. (You may cut and paste, if you dont want to type)

Comment: @PureData1 Just re-check the code to see that it's exactly the same as what you typed, except it's formatted code to be more easily readable. Also, I don't understand why you're being so aggressive with people that are trying to help you. I didn't modify your code in your question and put the working version of it. I just tested its syntax and it's correctly written. But again, as **showdev** said **"what is the error?"**. Start by giving more details than "depends on where I put the statement". Maybe show us this version of your code?

Comment: Thanks. If you cannot help. LEAVE. There are others responding to the same question without altering the question. Showdev has pointed that out as well. The error code is "Incorrect statement near'CASED'" - that is plain English

Comment: @PureData1 You are not a nice person. Good luck with your endeavours on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want perhaps?

```
SELECT  
       st.Name Territoryname,
       pp.LastName SalesPerson,
       ps.Name ShipMethod,
       CASE WHEN sc.CardType='Distinguish' THEN 'Cash' ELSE sc.CardType END AS CreditCardType,
       soh.OrderDate,
       soh.TotalDue
FROM    Sales.SalesOrderHeader soh
JOIN    Person.Person pp 
ON      soh.SalesPersonID=pp.BusinessEntityID
JOIN    Purchasing.ShipMethod ps 
ON      ps.ShipMethodID=soh.ShipMethodID
JOIN    Sales.CreditCard sc 
ON      sc.CreditCardID=soh.CreditCardID
JOIN    Sales.SalesTerritory st 
ON      st.TerritoryID=soh.TerritoryID
```

This will display`cash`where the CardType is`Distinguish`. Maybe it should be:

```
CASE WHEN sc.CardType IS NULL THEN 'Cash' ELSE sc.CardType END AS CreditCardType
```

if you want to display`cash`where the card type is missing (although I don't think this can happen as you are using inner joins, and not left joins).

Comment: Than you JPW. I LOVE your style.(Straight to the point). That is exactly what I intend to achieve. You rock!!!

Answer (score 0):

you do not need the CASE in the join. instead put the case in the select only:

```
SELECT ..., 
   CASE WHEN CardType = '' THEN 'Cash' ELSE CardType END AS CardType,
   ...
```

also, if some of the joined tables will not have corresponding rows in case of a cash payment you'll need to use `LEFT JOIN`s

Answer (score 0):

Your CASE statement is in the wrong place. You want it in the SELECT portion

```
select st.name Territoryname, pp.LastName SalesPerson, ps.Name ShipMethod, soh.OrderDate, soh.TotalDue, 
CASE sc.CardType
WHEN null THEN 'Cash' 
ELSE sc.CardType
END
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader soh
JOIN Person.Person pp ON soh.SalesPersonID=pp.BusinessEntityID
JOIN Purchasing.ShipMethod ps ON ps.ShipMethodID=soh.ShipMethodID
JOIN Sales.CreditCard sc ON sc.CreditCardID=soh.CreditCardID
JOIN Sales.SalesTerritory st ON st.TerritoryID=soh.TerritoryID
```

You also mention that it should say 'Cash' when CardType is empty, so please note I changed it to when 'Null' in the select statement instead of when 'Distinguish'

Comment: `CASE sc.CardType WHEN null ...` will never work, because it is equivalent to `CASE WHEN sc.CardType = null ...` and you probably know that you should test for NULL using `x IS NULL` rather than `x = NULL`. So, use the other CASE syntax for it: `CASE WHEN sc.CardType IS null ...`.